# How to make If statement fail with multiple and conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following list of tuples. I am trying to test a negative scenario to fail the condition.

```
>>> regop = [('1000', '63', 'Untaggged', '1000')]
```

I am trying to write a condition:

```
>>> if int(regop[0][0]) != 1000 and int(regop[0][1]) != 63 and regop[0][2] != 'Untaggged' and int(regop[0][3]) == 100:
...  print "error"
```

In this case, `int(regop[0][3]) == 100` is `False`, and rest 3 conditions are `True`, but as I have used `and`, shouldn't this `if` condition fail and print `error`? It dint print `Error`.
I am clueless on what is going wrong here. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: `True and False` evaluates to `False`, thus the condition will not be triggered and so `print "error"` will not be executed.

Comment: It will print "error" only if all of the values do not match. If you want it to print when one or more of the `!=` clauses are true, then use `or` instead of `and`

Comment: Got the point, thanks much @ metatoaster

Comment: Don't all the conditions evaluate to [false](https://ideone.com/nb9wWU)?

Comment: `int('1000') == 1000` is true therefore `int('1000') != 1000` is false, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need `or` instead of `and`, if you want the `if` to trigger on *any* of the conditions evaluating to `True`.

As an improvement to your current solution, I'd recommend the use of `any`.

```
vals = (1000, 63, 'Untaggged', 100)
if any(x != y for x, y in zip(regop[0], vals)):
    print('error')
```

`any` returns `True` if even a single condition evaluates to `True` inside the generator comprehension. Conversely, replace `any` with `all` if you want the resultant to be `True` only when *every* condition in the comprehension is `True`.

Using `any`/`all` eliminates the need to hardcode `x1 != y1 or x2 != y2 or ...` that many times, and results in concise code.